# put html canvas at the top left of page

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have the following html file:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1440" height="800" style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<body style="background-color:#FF0000;">

<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00"
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 2400, 2000) // background
    ctx.stroke()
</script>
```

which produces a page that looks like this:

[image]

Notice that the canvas begins slightly below and to the right of the top left corner. How can I place it exactly at the top left corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position `position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;`.

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1440" height="800" style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></canvas>

<body style="background-color:#FF0000;">

  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00"
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 2400, 2000) // background
    ctx.stroke()
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to the body and it will place the canvas to the top-left.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your css

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#00FF00;
}
canvas{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```